# Make gtm.js load on start, without any cookie

Tags: 9, cookies, google-analytics

I use this module and I cannot make it to load from the start gtm.js, without any cookie. If I don't load gtm.js from start, the whole Google Ads and Analitycs becomes useless. If I load gtm.js with cookies from start, I don't comply to EU regulations.

How can I configure the module to work with Google Tag Manager and comply to EU regulations?

These are the settings I am using.

> [image: settings]

Comment: Since the module's project page claims that it has built-in support for Google Tag Manager module, it is probably better to open a support request in the module's issue queue and help to improve the module's documentation.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I did that of course, but I haven't recieved any answers so far